# Erro ao gerar relatorio com parametro id

Tags: java, jasper-reports, relatório, ireport, jasper

Estou fazendo um pequeno sistema imprimir um orçamento passando como parâmetro o id. Ocorre a seguinte situação;
Pelo netBeans passo o id quando solicitado e aparece o relatório normal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando eu faço gerar o relatório pelo meu programa ele traz assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu método que gera o relatório:

```
 public void imprimeRelatorio() {

        ConexaoMySql co = new ConexaoMySql();
        co.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/poc");
        co.setUsuario("root");
        co.setSenha("");
        String src = "C:\\Users\\Administrador\\Documents\\Eduardo\\ControleOrcamento\\src\\vendas\\orcamento.jasper";


        Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        parametros.put("id",  (Integer.parseInt(inpId.getText())));



        JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
        try {
            jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(src, parametros, co.getConnection());
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TelaControle.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
        view.setVisible(true);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema era no sql do jasperReport inicialmente estava assim:

```
SELECT * FROM orcamento  WHERE id= $P{Id};
```

então alterei para `$P{id};` e resolveu o problema.